# Add Picture In Email Body

Tags: php

i am not too good with PHP and programming but still i am trying to learn it in every possible way. I need help from experts. My code to send email is as below. i am able to send email, but the problem is, picture is not displaying in email body and it's showing a cross sign. any possible idea and suggestion is appreciated.

```
<?php

function send_email($from, $to, $subject, $message){
$headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";

$headers .= "Return-Path: ".$from."\r\n"; 
$headers .= "CC: abc@gmail.com\r\n , xyz@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: \r\n";
//set content type to HTML 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) 
{

header("location:contact-us.php?msg=msgsent");

} 
else 
{
header("location:contact-us.php?msg=notsent");
}

}
//Function ends here
$from_email="";
$to_email="LMN@gmail.com";
$message.="<html><body background='images/bg11.jpg'>";
$message.="<p style=' color: #006789;'>Dear Team,</p> ";
$message.= "<p style=' color: #006789;'>You have received a feedback from $name & below are the details!!! </p>";
$message.= "<img src=images/c22.jpg>";
$message.="</body></html> ";
send_email(from_email,$to_email,$subject,$message);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a relative path:

```
<img src=images/c22.jpg>
```

When you open your mail, that path will mean nothing in a mail client and it is highly unlikely to exist on a webmail client. And if it does, it is not your image...

If you have that image stored on a web-server, you should use the absolute path to that image:

```
<img src="http://www.your-server.com/images/c22.jpg">
```

Comment: thanks brother it works for me. and it's quite easy as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a relative link, "images/c22.jpg", but you're sending this html in an email - there's no images/ directory relative to it to link to. If you wish to link to an image on the web, you can include a full url (http://someplace.com/images/bg11.jpg">). By default, those will usually not be displayed either - most email readers will filter them so as to not let you cause it to load remote content (tipping off that the email was opened, attempting funny business with malformated images, etc).

You can also attach an image to the email by setting the type to multipart/mixed and defining a boundary. Then send an image, defining a content-id in its headers, then your html linking to the content id as "cid:id-you-defined". Looks like this once in the email:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="NOTUSEDINTEXT"
This text only shows if the reader can't deal with MIME
--NOTUSEDINTEXT
Content-Id: id_for_later
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcU
FhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgo
KCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCAABAAEDASIA
AhEBAxEB/8QAFQABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAj/xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAFAEB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AJUAB//Z
--NOTUSEDINTEXT
Content-Type: text/html

<html><h1>Hi</h1><p>Here's an image <img src="cid:id_for_later"></html>
--NOTUSEDINTEXT--
```

.. but as you see it's slightly involved - might want to see if there's a php library that'll implement that (the mime headers and types) rather than pound them in yourself. But if you feel like dealing with it, inserting them yourself is ok too. And.. here too, some clients will filter them for safety unless you've clicked "Always show images" or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload your image on web server and give the absolute path to that image e.g:

```
<img src="http://www.yourwbesite.com/images/c22.jpg" alt="logo" />
```